# Can I invite/notify somehow another iPhone user that does not have the my application to a Game Center match?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, game-center

I'm making an iOS app that has the possibility to challenge friends trough Game Center. If i invite a friend that has the application it's ok but if he doesn't have it, then the find match Game Center controller says directly that he refuse the invitation.
Can i make to notify the other iPhone user see that he was challenged to a duel and offer him the option to install application from store and when he logs in Game Center the duel start automatically?

Comment: I can hardly stand the notifications from the apps I already have. It would be really annoying to get notifications for apps I didn't even buy/install. You can't and shouldn't do this. If the other user is not interested in the duel, your notifications will be SPAM.

Comment: The notification, coming from one friend from GameCenter shouldn't be considered spam..my opinion..

Comment: For an app i have NOT installed... how do you know whos my **friend**

Comment: you have there two buttons: Play Now and Invite Friend, that's how i know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: No you can't via GameCenter programatically